# Creating a grid of 1km x 1km

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grids-graticules

I would like to create a grid for 1km x 1km in one area from a satellite view map in JAPAN using EPSG: 6668 but this error always shows up " Horizontal spacing is too large for the covered area" even when I put the horizontal and vertical spacing at 1.[image: CLIP 1] And even using EPSG:4326-WGS 84 the same issue appears.

Comment: Try using UTM, if you are not sure which UTM zone you are in , then check this site: https://mangomap.com/robertyoung/maps/69585/what-utm-zone-am-i-in-#

Comment: Both coordinate systems that you have tried use degree as an unit, so the value "1" that you have entered corresponds to about 111 kilometers.

Comment: QGIS added those yellow triangles (warning signs) for exactly that reason ;-)

Answer (score 4):

[EPSG:6668](https://epsg.io/6668) (JGD2011) is in decimal degree units. You need to use JGD2011 UTM Zone ##, where ## is the zone number in which your data is located and has a meter unit.

There are six UTM zones ranging from Zone 51 to 56 in Japan, as you can see in the image below. Therefore, you need to choose the proper zone based on the location of your data.

[image]

You can refer to [ESRI Japan](https://www.esrij.com/gis-guide/coordinate-and-spatial/coordinate-system-japan/) (in Japanese) for more information.